# returning multiple arrays from a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function where I would like to return multiple arrays. I know that in c++ does not return an array, but instead returns a pointer to an array. For example:

```
int* function(double array[])
```

But what if I need to return multiple arrays (multiple pointers to arrays? say like 2-10). I have thought of one way of doing this. One would be to just pass the arrays to a void function by reference:

```
void function(int a[], int b[], double c[])
```

But then we might be passing a lot of arrays as input. I could package all my input arrays into a class, pass the class by reference, but this seems like unnecessary structure. What is the right way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `But what if I need to return multiple arrays` My first reaction would be "find another way", although if it really is warranted then wrap the arrays in a `struct`. Either way you should look into `std::array` which can be returned by value.

Comment: @nneonneo I am fairly new to c++ and was not aware that arrays were frowned on.

Comment: @user2697246: they are rather inconvenient, to be honest. `std::vector` is so much easier -- value semantics, pass-by-reference is not painful, and no manual memory management.

Comment: @user657267 Well I am trying to translate some matlab code to c++. This code involves a lot of functions that take multiple arrays as input and return multiple arrays as output. Basically I'm trying to figure out how to best design the c++ version (obviously matlab is significantly different from c++).

Comment: 'What is the right way to do this?' there is no right way, that's the beauty of programming! It all depends on the application. Btw, the solution you wrote is dangerous because 'function' doesn't know how much memory you're allocated for your arrays.

Comment: If you want to “return” three arrays, two of `int`s and one of `double`s like your code suggests, I don't see a way to do this in a type safe manner without introducing a data type that has three members of the correct type.  Maybe `std::tuple` could help you?

Comment: @user2697246 The most simple, direct way to return multiple arrays of fixed size would be something like returning a `std::tuple<std::array<int, size1>, std::array<int, size2>, std::array<double, size3>>`. You could use this with `std::tie` on the receiving end. Whether this is the "best" way or not is rather subjective but I'd imagine there are simpler ways depending on what the function is meant to be doing and what the arrays represent.

Comment: @chuck1 How would you write the function to let it know the memory being used?

Comment: @user2697246: as @user657267 suggested, you could use std::array, or you just pass the size of the array along with the pointer `void function(int* array, int size_of_array);`

Comment: @chuck1 oh ok I see. I didnt realize that one usually sent the size of the array as an additional input when modifying an array by reference. Thanks

Comment: @user2697246 You aren't passing your arrays by reference, `int a[]` means exactly the same thing as `int* a`, an array reference would be something like `int (&a)[10]`.

Comment: @user657267 "pass by reference" (in computer science jargon) means that the callee accesses the same variable as the caller; in C++ passing a pointer is a way of achieving this, because the callee can dereference the pointer to access the variable in question. I think OP meant that, rather than the C++ term "reference".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::vector`s instead of arrays:

```
void function(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b, vector<double> &c)
```

The function caller simply makes three vectors and passes them in:

```
vector<int> a, b;
vector<double> c;
function(a, b, c);
```

and the function can edit the vectors any way it likes (e.g. `a.resize(10); a[0] = ...`), since the vectors that the function uses are the same vectors that the caller passed in. In this way, the function can "return" multiple vectors by changing the vectors passed in by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `vector of vectors`

```
 std::vector<std::vector<double>> my2Dvec;
 std::vector<double> vec1, vec2, vec3;

 my2dvec.push_back(vec1);
 my2dvec.push_back(vec2);
 my2dvec.push_back(vec3);

 my2dvec[0].push_back(123.123);
 my2dvec[1].push_back(456.456);
 my2dvec[2].push_back(789.789);

std::cout << my2dvec[0][0] << std::endl; // 123.123
std::cout << my2dvec[1][0] << std::endl; // 456.456
std::cout << my2dvec[2][0] << std::endl; // 789.789
 //----------------------------------------
```

NOTE: vectors become increaseingly slow the more demensions you put into them. So if you have a 3d vector of vectors be mindful of the speed hit

Comment: Took it out. Hmmm I thought I did that recently. I'll test it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
void Function(unsigned char*&dat1, unsigned char*&dat2, unsigned char*&dat3, ...)
{
      dat1 = new unsigned char[10];
      dat2 = new unsigned char[20];
      dat3 = new unsigned char[30];
      ....
}
```

This will pass the pointer of the array by reference.